# How to implement a remember me function?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, local-storage, angular2-template

I am doing an Angular 4 application with node js backend. I did the login form, and all is good I want to implement the function "remember me".

This my login service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class loginService{
  rememberMe: boolean;
  constructor() { }

login(credentials) {
  sessionStorage.setItem('Name', credentials.firstName);
  sessionStorage.setItem('token', credentials.token);
}

getCostumer() {
  const user = {
    Name:  sessionStorage.getItem('firstName'),
    token: sessionStorage.getItem('token')
}
```

This is the component:

```
constructor(private signInService: SignInService, private router: Router, 
public dialog: MatDialog, private authService: AuthService) { }

ngOnInit() { }

  login(costumer) {
     this.loginService.login(costumer).subscribe((data) => {
       this.authService.login(data);
       this.router.navigate(['home']);
       this.dialog.closeAll();
      }, err => {
       this.message = err._body;
       console.log(this.message);
     });
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you have any error ? What did you try ?

Comment: Yeah, I think you already solved your problem by setting `sessionStorage.setItem('Name', credentials.firstName);
sessionStorage.setItem('token', credentials.token);`

Comment: your loginService class doesn't have a method `signIn`, which you also never declare in your constructor. The code you've posted makes absolutely no sense

Comment: It is not the problem , i want when i click into checkbutton on the  login form named "Remember Me" and login after if i open a new window of googlechrome i found my self connected or if i close the navigator and reopen it i found my self connected

Answer (score 17):

Use `localStorage` instead of `sessionStorage`

In your case, you can do something like this:

```
if (isRemberMeChecked) {
    ...
    localStorage.setItem('Name', credentials.firstName);
    localStorage.setItem('token', credentials.token);
    ...
} else {
    ...
    sessionStorage.setItem('Name', credentials.firstName);
    sessionStorage.setItem('token', credentials.token);
    ...
}
```

If you want to get `isRemberMeChecked` value globally you can use **angular service**

Answer (score 6):

What you want to do here is use **localStorage** for the **rememberMe** and **credentials.firstName**. The **credentials.token** you can store in the **sessionStorage**:

```
login(credentials) {
  localStorage.removeItem('Name');
  localStorage.removeItem('RememberMe');
  sessionStorage.setItem('token', credentials.token);
  if(rememberMe){
    localStorage.setItem('Name', credentials.firstName);
    localStorage.setItem('RememberMe', JSON.stringify(this.rememberMe));
  }
}
```

After a reload it will fetch the **RememberMe** and **Name**:

```
if(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('RememberMe')) !== null)
{
  this.name = localStorage.getItem('Name');
  this.rememberMe = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('RememberMe'));
}
```

Comment: And how i will did in the side of html and how service will know the value of remember me because i have the service in another file

Comment: where i put the second code ? in the function login ?

Comment: Where ever you reload the page. I would say on the ngOnInit()

Comment: If you do it correct you have to do nothing with the service. The service should behind your sumbit button to login the user. The rememberMe should only be for the login page to set and get the name value.

Comment: You put the setter after the subscribe in your login component and not in your service?

Comment: In my service, i want know how the service will know the value of remeberme if it is checked or no.

Comment: If you saved it in the localStorage and it's set to true you should be able to acces it with `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('RememberMe')) !== null){ this.rememberMe = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('RememberMe'));`
Itf it's null you can see it as false cause it's not set anyway.

Comment: can you please modify from my code it will be better

Comment: But, how the client-side code know the token, after closing the browser and reopen. Shouldn't we need the token to make a request to the rest resources?