# How to set User to Login using Remember Me in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to set the 'Remember Me' in my Login page.I set the localstorage session but I think, I miss a part in the service file that's why my service didn't response. I try the 
[Angular 4, remember me function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49508979/angular-4-remember-me-function) but didn't get the key.
Please kindly help.

Login.html

```
<h2>Login</h2>
<form [formGroup]="loginForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="username">Username</label>
        <input type="text" formControlName="username" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="name" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.username.errors }" />
        <div *ngIf="submitted && f.username.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
            <div *ngIf="f.username.errors.required">Username is required</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" formControlName="password" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="pwd" name="pwd" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.password.errors }" />
        <div *ngIf="submitted && f.password.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
            <div *ngIf="f.password.errors.required">Password is required</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label><input type="checkbox" formControlName="rememberMe" class="form-control">Remember me</label>
      </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button [disabled]="loading" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
        <img *ngIf="loading" src="data:image/gif;base64,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" />
        <a [routerLink]="['/register']" class="btn btn-link">Register</a>
    </div>

</form>
<div><p>Username :{{name}}</p>
    <p>Pwd:{{pwd}}</p>

</div>
```

Login.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { first } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { AlertService, AuthenticationService } from '../_services';

@Component({templateUrl: 'login.component.html'})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
    loginForm: FormGroup;
    loading = false;
    submitted = false;
    returnUrl: string;


    constructor(
        private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
        private route: ActivatedRoute,
        private router: Router,
        private authenticationService: AuthenticationService,
        private alertService: AlertService
    ) {
        // redirect to home if already logged in
        if (this.authenticationService.currentUserValue) { 
            this.router.navigate(['/']);
        }
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.loginForm = this.formBuilder.group({
            username: ['', Validators.required],
            password: ['', Validators.required]
        });

        // get return url from route parameters or default to '/'
        this.returnUrl = this.route.snapshot.queryParams['returnUrl'] || '/';
    }

    // convenience getter for easy access to form fields
    get f() { return this.loginForm.controls; }

    onSubmit() {
        this.submitted = true;

        // stop here if form is invalid
        if (this.loginForm.invalid) {
            return;
        }

        this.loading = true;
        this.authenticationService.login(this.f.username.value, this.f.password.value)
            .pipe(first())
            .subscribe(
                data => {
                    this.router.navigate([this.returnUrl]);
                },
                error => {
                    this.alertService.error(error);
                    this.loading = false;
                });
    }
}
```

Authenication.service

```
 import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { User } from '../_models';
import { tokenKey } from '@angular/core/src/view';
import { Token } from '@angular/compiler/src/ml_parser/lexer';
import { Key } from 'selenium-webdriver';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class AuthenticationService {
    private currentUserSubject: BehaviorSubject<User>;
    public currentUser: Observable<User>;
    isRemberMeChecked: boolean=true;
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
        this.currentUserSubject = new BehaviorSubject<User>(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser')));
        this.currentUser = this.currentUserSubject.asObservable();
    }

    public get currentUserValue(): User {
        return this.currentUserSubject.value;
    }

    login(username: string, password: string) {
        return this.http.post<any>(`/users/authenticate`, { username, password })
            .pipe(map(user => {
                // login successful if there's a jwt token in the response
                if (user && user.token && this.isRemberMeChecked) {
                    // store user details and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
                   localStorage.setItem('1','username')
                    //localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify({ token: 3, name: username }));
                    localStorage.getItem('1')
                }

                return user;
            }));
    }

    logout() {
        // remove user from local storage to log user out
        localStorage.removeItem('currentUser');
        this.currentUserSubject.next(null);
    }
}
```

I am new to Angular.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you put your code in stackblitz

Comment: ok @sagars01. I put the code in stackblitz

Comment: Share the link as well. - Thank you.

Comment: I provide all the code part in this.Please verify the updated code.

Comment: `isRemberMeChecked` is always undefined, no where in the code you are setting the value for that variable. Your login method only takes in username and password. So not sure what result you are expecting.

Comment: @penleychan That's the doubt I have. I didn't clear to place 'isRemberMeChecked'. The point is that If I am the user and if I login with Remember Me checkbox and if I logout then I dont  want to give m username and pwd again. It should remember my pwd.

Comment: I'm not asking what it does I know what you are trying to do. I already explained the problem of your code.

Comment: @penleychan I am not sure whether I done the IsRememberChecked and also about the code I have where to place the localstorage part.

Comment: I just updated my code. I still can't achieve my result. Pls verify.

Comment: I'd really recommend using Cookie auth for spa's. Each and every script you include on your website (like jquery, angular, bootstrap, ...) can read the visitor's localStorage and take a hike with his precious JWT. Even if the scripts are being referenced with the `<script>` tag instead of being bundled.

Answer (score 2):

## login.ts

```
loginForm = new FormGroup({
    email: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    password: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    rememberMe: new FormControl(false)
  });

this.authenticationService.login(this.f.username.value, this.f.password.value,this.f.rememberMe.value)
```

## Authenication.service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { environment } from '@env/environment';
import { Observable, BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { UserInUser } from '../../models/signInUser';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {
  isLoggedIn: boolean = false;
  httpOptions = null;
  rememberMe: boolean = false;

  private currentUserSubject: BehaviorSubject<UserInUser>;
  public currentUser: Observable<UserInUser>;

  constructor(
    public router: Router,
    private http: HttpClient
  ) //public ngZone: NgZone // NgZone service to remove outside scope warning
  {
    this.rememberMe = localStorage.getItem('rememberCurrentUser') == 'true' ? true : false;

    if ((this.rememberMe = true)) {
      this.currentUserSubject = new BehaviorSubject<UserInUser>(
        JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'))
      );
    } else {
      this.currentUserSubject = new BehaviorSubject<UserInUser>(
        JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('currentUser'))
      );
    }

    this.currentUser = this.currentUserSubject.asObservable();

    this.httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      })
    };
  }

  public get currentUserValue(): UserInUser {
    return this.currentUserSubject.value;
  }

  SignIn(username: string, password: string, isRememberMe: boolean) {
    return this.http
      .post<any>(environment.apiUrl + 'users/authenticate', { _id: username, password: password })
      .pipe(
        tap(user => {
          if (user && user.token) {
            if (isRememberMe) {
              this.resetcredentials();
              //your logged  out when you click logout
              localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));
              localStorage.setItem('rememberCurrentUser', 'true');
            } else {
              //your logged  out when page/ browser is closed
              sessionStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));
            }
            // login successful if there's a jwt token in the response
            this.isLoggedIn = true;
            this.currentUserSubject.next(user);
            return true;
          } else {
            return false;
          }
        })
      );
  }
  resetcredentials() {
    //clear all localstorages
    localStorage.removeItem('rememberCurrentUser');
    localStorage.removeItem('currentUser');
    sessionStorage.removeItem('currentUser');
    this.currentUserSubject.next(null);
  }

  logout() {
    //clear all localstorages and redirect to main publib page
    this.resetcredentials();
    this.router.navigate(['/'], { replaceUrl: true });
  }
   }
```

Comment: some issues with this code, including the assignment of true to this.rememberMe insteads of comparison check ==  in:   

if ((this.rememberMe = true)) {

Answer (score 0):

You can save the user state and jwt token on local storage .and use it in intercepter next request .use variable like isLogged in local storage 
Session storage will be cleared after session expired .so here we use localstorage insted