# How to implement remember me in login using cookies in angular 7

Tags: angular8

email and password will stored in cookies if we checked remember me.
how to do it?

```
import { CookieService } from 'ngx-cookie-service';
  loginForm: FormGroup;
  email: string;
  password: string;
  rememberMe:string;
constructor( private cookieService: CookieService ) { }
ngOnInit() {}
handleSubmit() {
    if (this.loginForm.valid) {
      this.authService
        .loginUser(this.loginForm.value)
        .subscribe(
          response => this.handleLoginSuccess(response),
          error => this.handleLoginFailure(error)
        );
```

Comment: *"email and password will stored in cookies"* Don't do that. If you really need to, store some server-generated token, but not the raw email and password.

Comment: Possibly duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49508979/angular-4-remember-me-function

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen token generated and stored in local storage so now how to stored in cookies if checked box true?